# PIL image _crop to tensor, in tensorflow

Tags: image, tensorflow

I am a student studying about deeplearning.
I'm using tensroflow framework and make a code.
So i have a question.
I make a crop image using Pil.image.crop
but when I training the Pil.image.crop can't assign to tensor.
so How can i assign cropped image to tensor.
Plz give me a advice.
Thank you.
here is my github address
https://github.com/dldudwo0805/DeepLearningPractice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with `tf.image.crop_and_resize`. Here is an example:

```
from scipy.misc import imread
img = imread('flower.jpg') 

# image placeholder
X = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.uint8, shape=(1, 300,300,3))

# You need to set the area to crop in boxes and resize it to in crop_size
Y = tf.image.crop_and_resize(X,boxes=[[.25,.25,.75,.75]], crop_size=[100, 100], box_ind=[0] )

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
out = sess.run(Y, {X:np.expand_dims(img,0)})
```